# Error in Syncing ALM QC (12.00) with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 using ALM Synchronizer (12.60)

Tags: testing, tfs-2015, alm, data-synchronization, hp-quality-center

I have used ALM Synchronizer to connect to TFS (2015).  I have established the initial connection and am trying to obtain the TFS schema. After starting the "Run integrity check" operation I am receiving the following error:

Fetching endpoint schema:

> buildEntitySchema: disconnected Error converting value
>   "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;S-1-5-21-220523388-1606980848-854245398-45204"
>   to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityDescriptor'.
>   Path 'authenticatedUser.descriptor', line 1, position 168.

At this point, I can see Micro Focus ALM Defect Schema in field mapping at Sychronizer client but TFS bug Schema is empty.

Assistance in interpreting this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronizer installation guide mentions a step to copy files from the specified location (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0) to the adapters directory for HP Synchronizer. 
This step is inaccurate as the necessary files are not present in the listed path.

I downloaded the  TFS2015.ZIP file from the link below:

https://softwaresupport.softwaregrp.com/doc/KM02568091

and put the files in the path (C:\Program Files\HP\HP ALM Synchronizer\ adapters\net2015).
Then I registered the "Register-TFS-Adapter.exe" file and restarted the synchronizer service.
The problem solved this way.